# How can WCF consuming data from database phpmyadmin?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

nice to meet you all. I'm new in here.

Just want to ask, how can my WCF consume data from database phpmyadmin?
I just tried my WCF consume data from database sqlserver and it works in my wpf app.

But I can't find a way how can my WCF access the data if my database is online.
is there any clue?

i try to change the data source into the IP at my database, it doesn't work.
here is my SqlConnection,

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Alfred-PC;Initial Catalog=alfred;Integrated Security=True");
```

This is the WCF

```
public class Jobs : IJobs
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Alfred-PC;Initial Catalog=alfred;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    Data data = new Data();
    List<Data> listdata = new List<Data>();

    public DataSet Details()
    {
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from data", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }

    public Data GetDetails(int jobid)
    {
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from data where id = " + jobid, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            data.userid = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
            data.firstname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            data.lastname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
            data.location = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
            ds.Dispose();
        }
        conn.Close();
        return data;
    }

    public List<Data> GetAllDetails()
    {
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from data", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            listdata.Add(
                new Data
                {
                    userid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                    firstname = dr[1].ToString(),
                    lastname = dr[2].ToString(),
                    location = dr[3].ToString()
                }
            );
        }
        conn.Close();
        return listdata;
    }
}
```

this is the WPF file

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox1.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            ServiceReference1.JobsClient jc = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
            var x = jc.GetDetails(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text));
            if (x.userid != 0)
            {
                textbox2.Text = x.userid.ToString();
                textbox3.Text = x.firstname;
                textbox4.Text = x.lastname;
                textbox5.Text = x.location;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("RecordNotFound ... !", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("EnterID", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.JobsClient jc = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = jc.Details().Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.JobsClient jc = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = jc.GetAllDetails() ;
    }

}
```

Comment: WPF and WCF and both .NET.  The way you connect should work in both.  Post you working WPF code and the non working WCF code.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a **database administration tool** - not a database in itself.

Comment: How is the `JobsClient` WPF uses connecting to the DB?  Also, you should run `conn.Open()` before you try to use the connection, and you should always dispose of your connections once you're done with them.  Keeping the connection as a field is not right, unless you implement `IDisposable` to dispose of it, and always properly dispose of your `Jobs` object as soon as you're through with it.  It'd be simpler to just use `using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need an example for the connection string.
So for the connection string format please look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

An example could be `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` if you are using the standard port and did not change it. In this case you won't use integrated security though (you will specify the username and password in the connection string) so check if that is possible for you.

Then you may use the MySQL Connector (Namespace `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` downloadable here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dotnet.html) and connect to the MySQL database programatically as explained in detail here http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson02.htm

Comment: Yesterday, I tried the localhost database at my computer. By using default address, 127.0.0.1 and also use the username and password that I created from phpmyadmin. It runs perfectly. 
Now, i just try with my database at my website. I create a username and password using phpmyadmin at my cpanel website. and I refer the server to the IP at remote database in my website. But when I run the app, it prompt. access is denied for user (using password YES). I think I already type the username and password correctly. Any solution? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're using integrated security.  In the case of the WPF app, so the account used to authenticate access to the DB is the account you're logged in as.  But in the WCF service, the account is controlled by the settings for the (IIS) server hosting it.  You have some options:

1. Change to use a username and password to connect to the DB
2. Change the DB to accept the account that the WCF service is trying to connect as (the DB should tell you in an error message or log)
3. Change the server settings to use a Windows account that has privileges

Comment: i tried no 1 before, it wont connect to the database. the login was failed for user that i set. I already created a username n password that give all the privileges. 

i dont really understand about the no2 n no3. change the DB? thats mean i change into my database? how can i change it?
and also how can i change the server settings? do you have an example for that no2 and no3? thanks.

Comment: If the login failed, then you didn't set something up right, either in the DB or in your connection string.  I don't know how to do this with your DB.  At this point, I can basically only suggest that you research it further yourself.

Comment: okay. if i want to search on google what should i type for the keyword? I try WCF consuming database at phpmyadmin it always show up using the SQL Server. have done with this? i mean have u try that your WCF consuming data from phpmyadmin?

Comment: As @marc_s said earlier, "PHPMyAdmin is a database administration tool - not a database in itself."  WCF doesn't connect to PHPMyAdmin.  PHPMyAdmin and WCF (should) each connect to the same MySQL DB.  Until you grasp this, you'll have nothing but trouble trying to work with this.  E.g. maybe you created a login for PHPMyAdmin instead of for the DB, and tried to use that in WCF.

Comment: @AlfredAngkasa What part of PHPMyAdmin is an admin tool and not a database do you now get?  +1 Tim for you patience