# What is the connection string if my database is host online, not in my local computer?

Tags: c#, php, .net, wpf, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can WCF consuming data from database phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064300/how-can-wcf-consuming-data-from-database-phpmyadmin)

I want to ask about the connection string that should i write at WCF. My database is host at phpmyadmin.
How should I write the connections string? if the database is using microsoft access or sqlserver that run at my computer, I done it already. Now, I'm curious if my database at phpmyadmin.

### Honestly, I already asked this question in this forum yesterday. I say a big thanks to whom answer my question but I dont think that is a answer. I'm sorry for being stupid and don't understand what you said yesterday. If you get mad, you don't need to answer. thanks.

Out of the topic, this my WCF code.

```
public class Jobs : IJobs
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User=ael;Password=123456;Integrated Security=False");
    
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    Data data = new Data();
    List<Data> listdata = new List<Data>();

    public DataSet Details()
    {
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from data", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }

    public Data GetDetails(int jobid)
    {
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from data where id = " + jobid, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            data.userid = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
            data.firstname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            data.lastname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
            data.location = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
            ds.Dispose();
        }
        conn.Close();
        return data;
    }

    public List<Data> GetAllDetails()
    {
        conn.Open();
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from data", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            listdata.Add(
                new Data
                {
                    userid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                    firstname = dr[1].ToString(),
                    lastname = dr[2].ToString(),
                    location = dr[3].ToString()
                }
            );
        }
        conn.Close();
        return listdata;
    }
}
```

this is the wpf

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox1.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            ServiceReference1.JobsClient jc = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
            var x = jc.GetDetails(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text));
            if (x.userid != 0)
            {
                textbox2.Text = x.userid.ToString();
                textbox3.Text = x.firstname;
                textbox4.Text = x.lastname;
                textbox5.Text = x.location;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("RecordNotFound ... !", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("EnterID", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.JobsClient jc = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = jc.Details().Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.JobsClient jc = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = jc.GetAllDetails() ;
    }
    
}
```

I already create a user at phpmyadmin, and use it at my WCF. but whenever I run, its show "login failed for user ael".
Is there something I need to change in the connection string?
thanks before.

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't a database. it's a management tool/front-end for MySQL. Much like Microsoft Access is just a management tool/front-end for the Jet database engine.

Comment: for ThiefMaster Sorry, thanks for clarify. actually maybe is not satisfied with the answer, but not satisfied about how their answer.

@MarcB yes, is management tool. and how about the connection string? maybe I could ask, how to get the connection string as same as i get from the Microsoft Access?

for Tim S. hoo.. "thanks" for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need an example for the connection string.
So for the connection string format please see [ConnectionsStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

For example, if you are using the standard port and did not change it:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Then you can to use the MySQL Connector (Namespace `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` [downloadable here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dotnet.html)) and connect to the MySQL database programatically as explained in detail in this tutorial: [Connection to the MySQL Server](http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson02.htm).

Comment: yes, thank you so much. this is the answer that i looking for. My program run perfectly. Special thanks to Mr.Jason De Oliveira